# How to passe object to component(directive) in Aangularjs 2?

Tags: angular

I have component 'ContactSaveForm' (or directive 'contact-save-form' in Angular 1), and I want to passe object (`person = { name: 'Max', second_name: 'Smith', age: 23 }` ) to my component:

```
<contact-save-form [person]="person"></contact-save-form>

@Component({
    selector: 'contact-save-form',
    templateUrl: 'something.html'
})
@Inject( Something)
export class ContactSaveForm {
    @Input()
    person: any;

    constructor (){
    console.log(this.person);
    }

}
```

But when I try to do `[person]` I recieve  - 'person'(as string).
I tried all options

```
<inner-app (event1)="ctrl.onIncrement()" (event2)="ctrl.onIncrement()"
                   [message1]="ctrl.message1" [(message2)]="ctrl.message2" message3="Hey, inner app... nothin'">
```

But it doesn't work(. Can any one help me? **I'm using ng-forward**!!!
I'm expecting to see after `console.log(person)`

> { name: 'Max', second_name: 'Smith', age: 23 }

Comment: That seems correct. From your code snippet you're passing a string, so getting *person* as a string is the expected behavior. But it sounds like that's not what you're expecting, can you update your question with more code and explaining what you're expecting?

Comment: Ok, I see, the update is fine, but there's still something missing. Where is the *person* object coming from? Are you trying to communicate two components?

Comment: @EricMartinez I'm transfering my angularj app to angularjs 2 by ng-forward. I call <contact-save-form [person]="person"></contact-save-form>  in still angularjs 1 directive, contact-save-form it's already Angularjs 2 Component. I can passe all variable to Angularjs 2 component except Objects.

Comment: Uhmmm... I couldn't really say then. I haven't used ng-forward. But if you can pass only strings you could try stringifying your object (`JSON.stringify(object)`) and then using parse to recast it to object (`JSON.parse(stringifiedObject)`).

Comment: @EricMartinez ok thanks. I will try!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to pass an object in the way you're describing is to use the banana box, as you've done with `message2`: `[(person)]="ctrl.objectWherePersonIsStored"`. If that isn't working for some reason, I'd try the following:

- Make sure your attribute name corresponds to the variable name in the dashes-to-camel-case relationship, by which I mean that a variable called `public myVariable` should be represented by an attribute named `my-variable`.
- Make sure your `@Input()` variable is marked public.